# How to set semantic-ui-ember dropdown value?

Tags: ember.js, dropdown, semantic-ui

I have a model, called *assessmentTestModel*, that is a list of *assessmentTests*. Each assessmentTest contains a unique identifier *id*, and *form* that is a reference to another object called *form*. Form also has a unique identifier, *id*.

For every assessmentTest in assessmentTestModel, I want to render a drop-down on the screen that's menu-items are all of the forms (I've already accomplished this). I also want them to have the selected default value of assessmentTest.form (This is the issue). Currently, when each drop-down is rendered, it displays the default text 'Select an Assessment Test'.

Here's an example of assessmentTestModel:

```
{ assessmentTestModel: [
      {
          id: '1029',
          form: '85'
      },
      {
          id: '1030',
          form: '87'
      },
      {
          id: '1031',
          form: '85'
      }
 ]
}
```

Here is my current .hbs file. I've tried setting the *value* attribute of the ui-dropdown to the id of the form, and the form object itself. Neither have worked.

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Assessment Tests</label>
    <ol>
        {{#each assessmentTestModel as |assessment|}}
            <li>
                {{#ui-dropdown value=assessment.form class="selection" onChange=(action 'selectForm' assessment)}}
                    <div class="default text">Select an Assessment Test</div>
                    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                    <div class="menu">
                        <div data-value="" class="item">All Items</div>
                        {{#each formModel as |form|}}
                            <div data-value="{{form.id}}" class="item">
                                {{form.name}}
                            </div>
                        {{/each}}
                    </div>
                {{/ui-dropdown}}
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the value of assessmentTest.form?

Comment: @HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi the value of assessmentTest.form in the back-end is string. However, I can do processing at the front-end to convert it to the JSON object 'form' if that leads to a solution.